# glassfish-resources.xml ignored with NetBeans 8.0.1?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I have just used NetBeans 8.0.1 and GlassFish 4.1 for 2 old projects which worked well with NetBeans 8.0 and GlassFish 4.0.

Now (with NetBeans 8.0.1) I get an error "tInvalid resource : jdbc/nameOfTheSource__pm" during the deployment of the projects.

The JDBC resource and the connection pool are defined by glassfish-resources.xml (generated by NetBeans when I defined a new entity with the option "Create Persistent Unit" and "New Data Source").

If I use directly glassfish-resources by the command add-resource of asadmin, on the server, all is working: the connection pool and the JDBC resources are created. So the problem does not come from this file.

It is as if glassfish-resources.xml were ignored during the deployment.

Did someone had the same problem (and have an explanation)?

My environment: 
NetBeans 8.0.1, 
GlassFish 4.1, 
Java DB 10.10.1.2 - (1495037) (from Java 8.0).

Related question : how glassfish-resources is used during the deployment? It is not included in the EAR or WAR files.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetBeans - "sun-resources.xml" vs. "glassfish-resources.xml"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256428/netbeans-sun-resources-xml-vs-glassfish-resources-xml)

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug of GlassFish: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=243034

I define my datasource in the application by @DatasourceDefinition instead of using glassfish-resources.xml but it is a workaround just for a datasource, not for other types of resources.

Comment: This is very interesting!  How do you use `@DataSourceDefinition`?  A more full answer would be awesome, but at least you give a starting point!

Comment: You put this annotation on an EJB (or a servlet). See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html. Else, instead of using glassfish-resources.xml, you can use the old name sun-resources.xml.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to [a NetBeans bug they say they had fixed](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233481) but seemingly they had not. As a solution, I also ended up abandoning `glassfish-resources.xml` altogether and using `@DataSourceDefinition` annotation instead.

My configuration uses a separate `DataSourceBean.java` file for `@DataSourceDefinition`:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/jdbc/myDataSource",
    className="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource",
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=myDB",
    user="myuser",
    password="mypassword"
)
public class DataSourceBean {
}
```

`persistence.xml` looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi=" http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="myUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:global/jdbc/myDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```