# ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource

Tags: java, mysql, exception, netbeans, glassfish-4

I am creating an enterprise java application using netbeans 8.0.1 java EE6 and glassfish server 4.1.1 attached with netbeans.

When I have created the db in mysql and connected successfully and created entity class from database and session bean for that entity class and I am going to deploy the application it gives this error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : java:module/custordermgt__pm
at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:81)
at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:62)
at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:136)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
```

What caused this exception?

Comment: you have a problem in your data ressource, you should to check your persistance.xml if you are using maven then you should to create your connection pool and JDBC ressources manualy

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to [a NetBeans bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233481). Take a look at the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921913/1429984